# Setting up Models for the first time and for repeated use

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm going to be creating 5-7 models representing my tables. From what I'm reading, separate files for each Model is recommended and then I can import them into my main files.

My question is in regards to `sync()` and the risks of running that multiple times.

Looks like `sync()` should only run once, for creating the tables for the first time, but after that, unless I'm making changes to the schema, I don't need to run `sync()` anymore. Rather, I'd do `save()` each time I'm doing changes to the data.

So what is the recommended setup for handling `sync()` after the tables were created? Should I check if the tables exist first? Or simply delete `sync()` from my code after I've created the tables and never add it back in? Maybe a specific Grunt task that includes/removes it based on whether the project is fresh or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use it all. I would rather create the tables and other structures myself, and then point the ORM at them. You can make it reusable as a SQL script.

At the very least, I would have the sync set up as a separate script, that I ran once. It might be handy when things changed, when you want to set up a new environment. I would not want that in my code - no reason for it to be there.